# How to call EJB

Tags: java, jvm, ejb

I need to call EJB (created using NETBEANS ide having glassfish server) from a plain java program (without using any IDE). I have been told to create both EJB and client in **different JVMs**, and then get them executed. (by different JVMs I dont mean different insatnces of a JVM).

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/CreatingEJB3UsingNetbeansAndGlassfish this may be helpful to you

Comment: @Hemant- I have already done this. I want to create my client ie plain java program without using IDE. If I use netbeans to create both then i guess it would be within same JVM. The important question here is how can I call a EJB from different JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB

You can use any IDE to create your client application, for testing purposes you would have to move it to another machine and configure it to connect to your running glassfish instance (look into part 4 in the mentioned document)

Answer (score 0):

just as what you do between different JVM instances.

put a interface jar in your class path and lookup ejb instance from JNDI.